# MPI_Init_thread Error When Integrating LAMMPS and Parallel Python in Slurm Script

Tags: python, linux, mpi, cluster-computing, mpi4py

I am attempting to submit a Slurm script on my school's clusters, aiming to perform LAMMPS calculations and post-processing with MPI-based parallel Python in a single script. However, I encountered an error. After experimenting, I have distilled the script to its minimal form that consistently triggers the error. my Slurm file looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --job-name=xx
#SBATCH -N 1
#SBATCH -n 48
#SBATCH -o %J.out
#SBATCH -e %J.err
#SBATCH --partition=xxx

source /data/soft/profile.d/lammps.sh
source activate env
mpirun -np $SLURM_NPROCS order/order.py
```

The "lammps.sh" file imports necessary environment variables for LAMMPS calculations, and its content is essentially:

```
LAMMPS_HOME_DIR=/data/soft/lammps/29Oct20
export PATH=${LAMMPS_HOME_DIR}/bin:$PATH
export LIBRARY_PATH=${LAMMPS_HOME_DIR}/lib:${LAMMPS_HOME_DIR}/external_libs/lib:${LAMMPS_HOME_DIR}/external_libs/lib64:$LIBRARY_PATH
```

The "env" is a virtual environment with mpi4py installed. "order.py" is a file using mpi4py. When I submit the file, I receive the following error:

```
*** An error occurred in MPI_Init_thread
*** on a NULL communicator
*** MPI_ERRORS_ARE_FATAL (processes in this communicator will now abort,
***    and potentially your MPI job)
[node2:250691] Local abort before MPI_INIT completed completed successfully, but am not able to aggregate error messages, and not able to guarantee that all other processes were killed!
```

This error repeats 48 times. However, when I comment out the first line (i.e., source /data/soft/profile.d/lammps.sh), the remaining Python parallel part runs successfully.

I am confident in the correctness of my parallelization. Therefore, I would like to understand the cause of the error and whether there are approaches to have both sections (LAMMPS and Python) coexist or alternative ways to achieve the same effect.